# List with different object types?

Tags: vb.net, list, generics

Can I have a List containing one string and two numbers? Or I can only have one type of element?

Comment: What do those objects represent? Does it make sens to have different types in the list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If that's the kind of functionality you want, then I would look at the non-generic [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) class.

**Update**

For those of you who aren't going to read the huge comment chain...it looks like Adam Robinson is on to something using `List<object>` over `ArrayList`. Both will work but on large collections it seems like `List<object>` is measurably faster than `ArrayList`.

Comment: I would advocate `List<object>`. There's really no need to use `ArrayList` anymore.

Comment: @Adam - Why go List<object> and use something that is meant to be type-safe non-type-safe rather than using something that was meant to store different objects to begin with?

Comment: @Justin: You aren't making it non-type-safe, you're making it type-safe to the closest common ancestor, which is `object`. I would choose `List<T>` here because you don't *gain* anything by using `ArrayList` (i.e. it doesn't do anything that `List<object>` doesn't), and it would be consistent with my *other* lists. In other words, I use `List<T>` when I need a list; I don't use `List<T>` when my objects are in a tight inheritance hierarchy and `ArrayList` when they aren't.

Comment: @Justin: In addition, I'm not sure you can reasonably argue that `ArrayList` was "meant to store different objects to begin with". `ArrayList` was introduced before the advent of generics. Yes, you *could* store different types of objects, but I don't think it was designed specifically for that; it just happened to store heterogeneous objects as well as it stored homogeneous objects.

Comment: Someone said performance was better if I didn't use ArrayList. Is it significant? I am probably going to make.... hundreds, or thousands, dunno.

Comment: @Omega - The performance difference is going to come from the boxing/unboxing of value types. No matter if you use ArrayList or List<object>, you're going to incur that performance penalty.

Comment: @Omega: The difference is minimal with reference types (or when you're boxing anyway, as you are here), but `List<T>` is generally regarded as slightly faster.

Comment: @Omega, @Justin: In a quick anecdotal test using System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch, adding one million ints to a `List<object>` took 83 ms, whereas adding the same one million ints to an `ArrayList` took 181 ms.

Comment: @Adam - Now that is interesting. I would've expected performance to be closer inline...is there any chance any of the extra time could be attributed to JIT compilation (I'm guessing not based on the order you listed things, but I had to ask anyway).

Comment: @Justin: I don't think so; I ran it three times (the second pass was slower on both, oddly enough), and each time the `List<T>` was (relatively) significantly ahead. I mean, 181ms for a *million* boxing and insert operations is not exactly slow, but the difference was measurable. I was expecting them to be closer, too.

Answer (score 4):

You can. A list of Objects can do that. But, you lose type safety with that and also design time intelliSense.

What do you want to do? You could also use a class with 3 members.

Answer (score 4):

No, containers like `List(Of T)` store *exactly one type* `T` of elements. You can, though, make this one type *consist* of one string and two numbers.

```
Structure Foo
    Public Desc As String
    Public x As Integer, y As Integer
End Structure

Dim List = New List(Of Foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you can.

```
dim myVehicles as new list(of object)
dim myCar as new car
dim myBike as new bike
dim mySecondCar as new car


myVehicles.add(myCar)
myVehicles.add(myBike)
myVehicles.add(mySecondCar)
```